# Identifying Google Tag Manager tag from within the page

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

I'm going through some legacy code with a lot of tag manager tags in it. Is there a way to tell which tag is applied in the page **from the code or the page itself**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activate the preview mode in GTM, it will show a panel in your browser that tells you which tag has been fired under what condition.

Else install Ghostery and use it to block GTM. What remains are tags inside the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

If the page you are looking for is not yours, you could look into this file: http://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXXXX . Here are the fired tags visible.

Another way is installing the [Google Tag Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk) for Google Chrome. You can find all Google tags that are fired on the page from multiple GTM containers.